# Placement of a triangle at the bottom of a div, when divs are nested, etc

Tags: css

I am trying to use [this effect that positions a triangle at the bottom of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176948/horizontally-center-small-triangle-at-bottom-of-div-and-resize-responsively-and) on the block of code below, but I'm not sure if it's because of the nested divs or the section tag, I can not get it to work.

**This is what I am trying to achieve: (This is a PNG I mocked up)**
[image]

**However, I am currently seeing this (jsfiddle link):**

http://jsfiddle.net/hTp6y/

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <section class="vc_section_wrapper has_bg_color">
        <div class="bg-layer" style="background-color: rgb(114, 114, 255); height: 347px;" data-inertia="0.1">
        </div>
        <div class="wpb_row row-fluid">
            <div class="span12 wpb_column column_container">
                <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                    <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
                        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam nec odio ac lectus mattis pellentesque vel eu erat. Aliquam a libero non quam molestie interdum in ut urna.</p>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="vc_section_wrapper has_bg_color">
        <div class="bg-layer" style="background-color: rgb(158, 27, 52); height: 227px;" data-inertia="0.1">
        </div>
        <div class="wpb_row row-fluid">
            <div class="span12 wpb_column column_container">
                <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                    <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
                        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                            <p>Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In varius posuere elit, nec ultrices ligula posuere in. Vestibulum ut sollicitudin eros, et vestibulum magna. .</p>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.vc_section_wrapper .bg-layer {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    left: 0;
}

.vc_section_wrapper.has_bg_color > .wpb_row, .vc_section_wrapper.has_bg_img > .wpb_row { 
    padding-top: 40px;  
    position: relative;
}

.triangle-down{
    width: 2.5%;
    height: 0;
    padding-left:2.5%;
    padding-top: 2.5%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;right:0;
    margin:auto;
    top: 100px;
    z-index:1;
}
.triangle-down:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left:-50px;
    margin-top:-50px;

    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 50px solid pink;
}
```

I don't know if this is solely a CSS change, I have doubts over if I have placed this line of code in the correct place:

```
<div class="triangle-down"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace it here:

```
<div class="bg-layer" style="background-color: rgb(158, 27, 52); height: 227px;" data-inertia="0.1">
  <div class="triangle-down"></div>
</div>
```

And rewrite `top:100%` to `top:0` in class `triangle-down`.

http://jsfiddle.net/hTp6y/1/

Comment: Thanks @gial for the answer, it worked straight away when I added it to my code.

Answer (score 1):

I would go about this a little different.

The div that contains the triangle,

Place `position: relative;` on it, then you can just use `top: 100%;` to get the triangle right at the bottom.

css:

```
.tri {
    border-top: 20px solid gold;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FhDc9/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the other answers are correct. But I think this is a good chance to use a css after class to clean up your html and simplify things. Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xVKkL/).

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.top:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15px;
  border-top: 20px solid lightgray;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
}
```