# Make a CSS generated triangle appearing at the bottom of the div half the size

Tags: css

I am having a very hard time understanding what I have to change in order to impact the size of this CSS triangle (as originally defined on [this stackoverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176948/horizontally-center-small-triangle-at-bottom-of-div-and-resize-responsively-and)). I am looking for the same effect but about 50% smaller triangle.

I noticed in the referenced stackoverflow post @DanielD noted the following:

> 1) (padding-left + width)/padding-top = (border-left + border-right)/border-top = base/height
>
> 2) margin-left = -border-left = -border-right
>
> 3) margin-top = -border-top
>
> 4) width = padding-left

But when I try to follow this I get completely muddled.

This is the current code I have:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fakeguybrushthreepwood/xcTAn/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="top">
    <div class="triangle-down"></div>
</div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.top
{
    background: pink;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.bottom
{
    background: lightGreen;
    height: 100px;
}
.triangle-down{
    width: 3%;
    height: 0;
    padding-left:3%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;right:0;
    margin:auto;
    top: 100px;
    z-index:1;
}
.triangle-down:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left:-50px;
    margin-top:-33px;

    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 33px solid pink;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change: `padding-left:1.5%;
    padding-top: 1%;` within the triangle-down it should change the size to half of what you originally had.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xcTAn/2/) to also change `width: 1.5%;`

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: The problem with doing this is it seems that it's knocked out the centering, have a look here: http://snag.gy/2tkPs.jpg

Comment: Oh nice catch, I didn't even notice that.  What if you cut the width in half too?  `width: 1.5%;`  It seems to fix that 'buffer' for me.  [Fiddle Update](http://jsfiddle.net/xcTAn/2/)

Answer (score 1):

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/JnDhC/6/)

Since the triangle is made solely of borders, you have to affect each of the borders of the `:after` elements. Then you have to compensate for the change in size by changing the `margin-top` and `margin-left` values

```
.triangle-down:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left:-25px;
    margin-top:-25px;

    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    border-top: 25px solid pink;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately with this it seems the proportions are different to what the original one is. The triangle in the original post seemed flatter, I've tried to adjust it but still making a mess of things.

Comment: The proportions I gave give exactly half the area. Perhaps try border left and top of 50 and margin-left of -50 instead. What you actually want is not clear

Comment: Hey Zach, I need the triangle to be half the current size it is in the example above. Sorry if my question was not clear - perhaps this makes it clearer: http://i.imgur.com/BqFuXLt.png

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot help you any further because the sizes are relative. Play with the values until you get it as you'd like using this approach. It just takes replacing the 25s with whatever number you're looking for or by changing the proportions